# SQLite takes too much time on using OR condition with WHERE clause

Tags: sqlite, select, where-clause

I have a SQLite database (table) with **100 million rows**.

**Table schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    u_id      VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
    u_status  BOOLEAN,
    u_country VARCHAR(2),
    u_score   INT
);

CREATE INDEX dex_sta ON users (u_status);
CREATE INDEX dex_cou ON users (u_country);
CREATE INDEX dex_sco ON users (u_score);

CREATE INDEX dex_sns ON users (u_status, u_score);
CREATE INDEX dex_mul ON users (u_status, u_country, u_score);
```

When I use these below simple queries without choosing multiple countries I got response in **15 ms**.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_status = 1 AND u_country = 'US' ORDER BY u_score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100000;

SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_status = 1 AND u_country = 'IN' ORDER BY u_score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100000;
```

## Problem starts from this below query

When I try to match multiple countries with **OR** condition query takes **60 seconds** to respond.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_status = 1 AND (u_country = 'US' OR u_country = 'IN') ORDER BY u_score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100000;
```

## Query Improvement 1:

When I force query to use specific INDEX via (**INDEXED BY**) it responded in **1 second**

```
SELECT * FROM users INDEXED BY dex_mul WHERE u_status = 1 AND (u_country = 'US' OR u_country = 'IN') ORDER BY u_score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100000;
```

## Query Improvement 2:

When I'm using **UNION ALL** query it takes **500 milliseconds** to respond

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_status = 1 AND u_country = 'US'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_status = 1 AND u_country = 'IN'
ORDER BY u_score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100000;
```

Is it possible to get response in **< 50 ms** like first query with matching multiple countries?

Comment: Please post the explain plan for the query.

Comment: `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100000;` so, it is like starting from `100000th` largest element in the entire dataset?

Comment: Your `dex_mul` index makes the `dex_sta` one useless, btw, since the latter is a prefix of the former. See https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#_multi_column_indices for details. (The `dex_cou` and `dex_sco` ones are unlikely to be used at all in those queries either; confirm with `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` though)

Comment: You also should try to avoid the large `OFFSET`. See https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results for discussion and alternatives depending on what you're doing.

Comment: Finally,  running [ANALYZE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) on the table might help a bit if you haven't already done so. At the very least the query planner will be able to make a better decision about which one of those indexes to use.

Comment: Oh yeah. Depending on the distribution of your data, an index on `users(u_country, u_status, u_score)` might be better. Add it, re-`ANALYZE`, and see which one `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` says is being used now and if it's the one, benchmark away.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `OR` condition in the query doesn't allow the use of Indexes. You can convert your query to `UNION ALL` clause -

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE u_status = 1 AND u_country = 'US'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE u_status = 1 AND u_country = 'IN'
ORDER BY u_score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100000;
```

This might solve your problem.